# Angular: Disabling child control updating the parent form Pristine status

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an angular form like this

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
     details: this._fb.group({
         originId: [null, Validators.required],
         
         ... some more child controls
     }),
     ... some more child controls      
});
```

On `ngOnInit()` when certain conditions fulfil I am marking the form dirty and touched, like this

```
this.form.markAsDirty();
this.form.markAsTouched();
```

After this I get `this.form.isPristine` as `false` which is right, which is what I wanted.

Then later I make control `originId` disable like this to disable originId

```
this.form.get('details').get('originId').disable();
```

But the problem is, as soon as I disable the originId it updates the pristine status of the parent form to `true`, so this `this.form.isPristine` becomes `true` which I do not want.

I am not getting why does setting the child control updates the parent form pristine status.

Can anybody point out what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AbstractControl.disable` method propagates the disable flag to all direct ancestors as its default behavior which in your case results in your entire form being marked as disabled.

see: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable

To fix this, include the `onlySelf: boolean` property in the disable options object.

```js
this.form.get('details').get('originId').disable({onlySelf: true});
```